# PostgreSQL PDO driver for php 7.0

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I just migrated to php 7.0 from 5.6 version. Now I can not connect to my PostgreSQL database from command line (actually it's yii2 command). It throws an error:

```
Error: could not find driver
```

Running `apt-get install php7.0-pgsql` didn't help. Server is on Debian 8 (jessie).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing old packages and install new ones again helped me.

```
$ x="$(dpkg --list | grep php | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}')"
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove $x
```

Thanks to the [cyberciti's article](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/installing-php-7-on-debian-linux-8-jessie-wheezy-using-apt-get/)